# Setting automatic dividers when merging groups

Tags: notebooks, gui-construction, cells, user-interface

Imagine I have my code split into multiple sections, like so

[image]

Suppose I now select all cells and merge them, getting

[image]

Is it possible to automatic set a divider between the different code sections? I'm looking for something like

[image]

A code to apply customizable dividers to merged tagged cells would be ideal. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it should be straightforward to prepend some custom comment to the box structure of each selected cell, before telling the front-end to merge them.

Answer (score 1):

Something simple like this?

```
  Column[
    {
      code1,
      code2,
      code3
    },
    Dividers -> {None, {All, 4 -> None}}
 ]
```